# SQL query with EXCEPT doesn't work in Golang

Tags: sql, go

I can't understand why my INSERT query doesn't properly work with parameters, but works fine with direct values in it.

Golang, Postgres.

This code works fine:

```golang
fmt.Printf("connected to %s\n", ec.DBName)
q := `
INSERT INTO some_table (name, num) VALUES ('sample',20)
EXCEPT
SELECT name, num FROM some_table;`
_, err = db.Query(q)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

But this one raises an error:

```
fmt.Printf("connected to %s\n", ec.DBName)
q := `
INSERT INTO some_table (name, num) VALUES ($1,$2)
EXCEPT
SELECT name, num FROM some_table;`
_, err = db.Query(q, "sample", 20)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

The error is "pq: EXCEPT types text and integer cannot be matched"

Comment: I don't know much about go but you can send both values as string and try to cast them to the desired types. Something like this - 
q := `
    INSERT INTO some_table (name, num) VALUES (cast($1 as text), cast($2 as int))
    EXCEPT
    SELECT name, num FROM some_table;`
    _, err = db.Query(q, "sample", "20")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send both values as string and try to cast them to the desired types via sql. Something like this -

```
q := `
INSERT INTO some_table (name, num) 
VALUES (cast($1 as text), cast($2 as int)) 
EXCEPT 
SELECT name, num FROM some_table;`
_, err = db.Query(q, "sample", "20")
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```